# CURLE_UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL - ftp download fails

Tags: libcurl

i use cURL (installed via vcpkg). Also openssl installed via vcpkg for a c++ project on VS 2019.
The problem:

```
 CURLE_UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

I used this example:
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ftpsget.html

with corrected connection and file data. The FTP server is filezilla. I checked the connection and file
download with filezilla client. All fine.

When i use the sample from link, i get the CURLE_UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL and in my FTP server i can't see
any connection try.

The error is described like this:

```
The URL you passed to libcurl used a protocol that this libcurl does not support..
```

Verbose information is:

```
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x148090e0b38; line 1356 (connection #-5000)
* Protocol "ftp" not supported or disabled in libcurl
* Closing connection -1
* Expire cleared (transfer 0x148090e0b38)
```

I check the internet for the error message above and none of those i found solved my problem.
It seems not to be a format problem or problem related to wrong url .

So my question is, where can i enable this ? Do i need additional packages ? Or is the problem elsewhere ?

Many thanks

Comment: Your libcurl was built with FTP disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Mean while i figured out how to accomplish this using latest curl command line tool (**version 7.68.0**) on windows:

```
curl -u my_user:my_password --ftp-ssl ftp://my_ip/my_relative_path/my_file --insecure  -o my_file
```

The file for download is on a server where a FileZilla FTP server is working. This server cyphers with a self created cert. The curl client only accepts this, when using flag:

```
--insecure
```

So far, i could not find the related options for my c++ curl. Perhaps it is not possible at all, because sources available through vcpkg are not (yet) up to date. But i want to stick with vcpkg. For me, this solutions: using command line tool instead, works fine.

---

One more hint, which is important: curl version **7.64.00 works NOT**. You get error:
curl: (35) schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed